# intel-xdk: can we get the source code for different platforms?

Tags: intel-xdk

I am using intel XDK *NEW* build 0419. I am working on it since 2-3 weeks. Everything is going fine. But I want the source code of android build (or any platform). How can I get this, if its possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that's possible, Intel XDK is free to use and I heard that an old version of their container was available as opensource, but not anymore.

Anyway, you can ask them yourself at their [forums](https://forums.html5dev-software.intel.com/), they answer all questions relatively fast :)